# Unable to Resolve dependency:app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve io.anyline:anylinesdk:5

Tags: android, android-studio

I am working on one android project created by someone. After I open this project in my Android studio, it gives an error:

> ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath':
>   Could not resolve io.anyline:anylinesdk:5.
>
> ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for
>   ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve
>   io.anyline:anylinesdk:5.

```
//Build.gradle of my project
        apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
        apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
        apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
        android {
            compileSdkVersion project.ext.compile_sdk_version
            defaultConfig {
                applicationId "com.xyz"
                minSdkVersion 23
                targetSdkVersion 26
                versionCode 5
                versionName "1.0.4"
                testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
                ndk {
                    abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a'
                }
                multiDexEnabled true
            }
            sourceSets { main { assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets', 'src/main/TrainedModels'] } }
            buildTypes {
                release {
                    minifyEnabled false
                    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

                }
            }


            compileOptions {
                sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
                targetCompatibility = '1.8'
            }
            lintOptions {
                checkReleaseBuilds false
                abortOnError false
            }
        }
        repositories {
            flatDir {
                dirs 'libs'
            }
            maven {
                url 'https://anylinesdk.blob.core.windows.net/maven/'
            }
            mavenCentral()
        }


        dependencies {
            implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
            testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
            implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:$support_version"
            implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$support_version"
            implementation "com.android.support:design:$support_version"
            implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$support_version"
            implementation "com.android.support:preference-v14:$support_version"
            implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.8.0'
            implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
            implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'
            implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.4.1'
            implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0'
            implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.3.0"
            androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'

            implementation 'io.anyline:anylinesdk:5@aar'

            implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.1.1'

            implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
            implementation 'com.googlecode.libphonenumber:libphonenumber:7.2.2'
        //
            implementation ('com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.6.0'){
                force=true
            }
            implementation ('com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-api-phone:11.6.0'){
                force=true
            }
        //Optional for phone number hint
            implementation ('com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.6.0'){
                force=true
            }
            implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"

        }
        repositories {
            mavenCentral()
    }
```

[image: Images of Error]

Could Anybody help me.

Comment: follow this link https://github.com/Anyline/anyline-ocr-examples-android

Answer (score 1):

Here the issue is anyline sdk integration

Add Anyline SDK to the dependencies in build.gradle

```
repositories {
//add the anyline maven repo
maven { url 'https://anylinesdk.blob.core.windows.net/maven/'}
}

dependencies {
//add the anyline sdk as dependency (maybe adapt version name)
compile 'io.anyline:anylinesdk:3.6.1@aar'
//... your other dependencies
}
```

Or via local copy of the aar

Copy the .aar to the libs directory of your project (app/libs) and adapt build.gradle.

Add Anyline SDK to the dependencies in build.gradle

```
//root section of the file
repositories {
flatDir {
    dirs 'libs'
}
}

dependencies {
compile(name:'anylinesdk-3.6.1', ext:'aar')
//... your other dependencies
}
```

Hope this will resolve.....

Comment: After formatting system, this error arises before formatting system there is no error regarding this project my android studio was able to resolved all the dependencies

Comment: @Apoorv, it's clear that some of your dependency files are gone most probably that's aar file

Comment: Varma Lanke,I think there is no aar file because anylinesdk directly coming from maven in my project and i have paid key of that anylinesdk.

Answer (score 0):

clean the project first(build->clean project)
then migrate to android x(Refactor -> migrate to androidx)
allow to changes recommended by the android studio

Answer (score 0):

Error has resolved.Now Android studio is able to download anyline sdk.this error has been occured because url 'https://anylinesdk.blob.core.windows.net/maven/' had been blocked ITSEC of my company.

Thanks for your help